# How can I check the loss when training RoBERTa in huggingface/transformers?

Tags: logging, huggingface-transformers, loss, roberta-language-model

I trained a RoBERTa model from scratch using `transformers`, but I can't check the training loss during training using

https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/blog/blob/master/notebooks/01_how_to_train.ipynb

In the notebook, loss is printed every 500 steps, but there is no training loss logged during training:

```
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20703/20711 [4:42:54<00:07,  1.14it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20704/20711 [4:42:54<00:05,  1.24it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20705/20711 [4:42:55<00:05,  1.20it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20706/20711 [4:42:56<00:04,  1.18it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20707/20711 [4:42:57<00:03,  1.19it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20708/20711 [4:42:58<00:02,  1.16it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20709/20711 [4:42:59<00:01,  1.14it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|█████████▉| 20710/20711 [4:43:00<00:00,  1.13it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|██████████| 20711/20711 [4:43:00<00:00,  1.45it/s][A  
Iteration: 100%|██████████| 20711/20711 [4:43:00<00:00,  1.22it/s]  
Epoch: 100%|██████████| 13/13 [61:14:16<00:00, 16952.06s/it]  
Epoch: 100%|██████████| 13/13 [61:14:16<00:00, 16958.16s/it]

compress roberta.20200717.zip on ./pretrained
save roberta.20200717.zip on minio(petcharts)
```

No values are printed for the loss, so I don't know if the training converged well or not. How can I monitor the loss during training?

Answer (score 0):

Just try executing the notebook again (e.g. directly in colab) using a newer version of the library, for which logging has been reworked. Be mindful that `Trainer` may need a slightly different set of arguments because of deprecations.

The example shows the training loss in output without issues

[image: Training metrics]

I'm using

```
tokenizers                    0.9.4          
transformers                  4.0.0rc1
```

and these training arguments seem to do the job:

```py
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./EsperBERTo",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=64,
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset,
)
```